# Android ADB API from C/C++ Applications

Tags: c++, android, c, adb

I want to communicate to the adb service on my android phone (via USB) from my c/c++ application.

It has to be "fast", so going out to the shell to run a Java program is out of the question.

Are there any examples anywhere of this being done, and the API for this type of connection?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but the c/c++ application is running host(PC)-side.

Comment: If this was a comment to hackbod's answer, you should post it as a comment attached to that answer. Otherwise, you should edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Android applications don't have access to the adb socket.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but the c/c++ application is running host(PC)-side.